# Learning rate in logistic regression with sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In sklearn, for logistic regression, you can define the penalty, the regularization rate and other variables. Is there a way to set the learning rate?

Answer (score 6):

`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` doesn't use SGD, so there's no learning rate.

I think `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier` is what you need, which is a linear classifier with SGD training.

### References

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html

Comment: Thank you for the links and answers. So, how is LogisticRegression implemented in sklearn? I am not sure I fully understand what is the coordinate descent they use for it.

Answer (score 5):

According to [sklearn's Logistic source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L1176), the solver used to minimize the loss function is the SAG solver (Stochastic Average Gradient). [This paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00860051/document) defines this method, and in [this link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/linear_model/sag.py) there is the implementation of the sag solver. This implementation of the solver uses a method to obtain the step size (learning rate), so there is not a way that you can change the learning rate (unless you want to change the source code).